# What are these javascript syntax called? "/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/"

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email, syntax

I have the following code as part of my email validation script. I'd like to learn more about the variable `reg` but don't know how to find relevant information because I do not know what the syntax is called. Could someone direct me to the proper resource or tell me the name of this type of syntax?

```
function validate(form_id,email) {
   var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
   var address = document.forms[form_id].elements[email].value;
   if(reg.test(address) == false) {
      alert('Invalid Email Address');
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Also, your regex is very wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses/532972#532972.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a regular expression.

There are a lot of resources on regexes, and particularly about regexes in JS. Here is a guide that explains how to use them:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml

and a guide to the patterns themselves:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Answer (score 4):

Check out the nice wikipedia article:

- [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

---

> In computing, a regular expression,
>   also referred to as regex or regexp,
>   provides a concise and flexible means
>   for matching strings of text, such as
>   particular characters, words, or
>   patterns of characters. A regular
>   expression is written in a formal
>   language that can be interpreted by a
>   regular expression processor, a
>   program that either serves as a parser
>   generator or examines text and
>   identifies parts that match the
>   provided specification.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worry about something, thats nothing to worry about. Thats called Regular Expression AKA Regex. What this script is doing in this code? It is matching/validating the user input to only accept email addresses which are well formatted.

test@@@test.com (invalid)
test@test.com (valid)

Answer (score 1):

function check_email()
{

```
//          /^[+a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i    this anather  regular experession
var pattern = new RegExp(/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/);

if (pattern.test($('#form_email').val()))
{
    $('#email_error_message').hide();
}
else
{
    $('#email_error_message').html('Invalid Email');
    $('#email_error_message').show();
    error_email = true;

}
```

}

Comment: you can also  create  function  for this code  above  please  ,  It's also easy way

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular expression (regex). Find more information here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html.

Answer (score 0):

The expression to the right is called a regular expression.
You can get more info from : http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html